# How can I get the list of Wonders of the World using SPARQL from wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?countryLabel ?picture {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q209287
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P17 ?country }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?picture }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }  
}
```

Comment: which wonders? The seven or others?

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?typeLabel ?countryLabel ?picture WHERE {

VALUES ?type {wd:Q66108498 wd:Q209287}
?type ^wdt:P31/(wdt:P527)? ?item

OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P17 ?country. }

OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?picture. }

SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }

}`